# API Data to be displayed in Line Charts (react-chartjs-2)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to accurately use and display this API values in a line chart.

**API Call with Line Chart:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2'

let headers = {
  'QB-Realm-Hostname': 'XXXXXXXXXX.quickbase.com',
  'User-Agent': 'FileService_Integration_V2.1',
  'Authorization': 'QB-USER-TOKEN XXXX_XXX_XXXXXXX',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

class TotalLineChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = () => {    
    let body = {"from":"bpz99ram7","select":[3,6,80,81,82,83,86,84,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,101,103,104,105,106,107,109,111,113,115,120,123,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,477,479,480,481],"where": "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}","sortBy":[{"fieldId":6,"order":"ASC"}],"groupBy":[{"fieldId":40,"grouping":"equal-values"}],"options":{"skip":0,"top":0,"compareWithAppLocalTime":false}}

   fetch('https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: headers,
     body: JSON.stringify(body)
   }).then(response => response.json())
     .then( data => this.setState({ data })
     );
   }

  render() {
    const data = {
      labels: ['50', '100', '150', '200', '250', '300'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'TOTAL',
          data: [
            {x: this.state.data["6"].value, y: this.state.data["3"].value },
          ],
          fill: false,
          borderColor: '#00498D'
        },
      ],
    };

    const options = {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Line data={data} options={options} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default TotalLineChart;
```

**Example of API working rendering data:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

let headers = {
  'QB-Realm-Hostname': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.quickbase.com',
  'User-Agent': 'FileService_Integration_V2.1',
  'Authorization': 'QB-USER-TOKEN XXXXX_XXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
};

class JobsTableApi extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }    

  fetchData = () => {    
     let body = {"from":"bpz99ram7","select":[3,6,80,81,82,83,86,84,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,101,103,104,105,106,107,109,111,113,115,120,123,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,477,479,480,481],"where": "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}","sortBy":[{"fieldId":6,"order":"ASC"}],"groupBy":[{"fieldId":40,"grouping":"equal-values"}],"options":{"skip":0,"top":0,"compareWithAppLocalTime":false}}

    fetch('https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then( data => this.setState({ data })
      );
    }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

      if (data === null) return 'Loading Job Data...  ';

    return (
      <div>
          {Object.keys(data["data"]).map(item => (
            <div key = {item}>
              {data["data"][item][6].value}
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default JobsTableApi;
```

My Idea is that I have multiple line charts and all the data from the API, I'm attempting to display this data on line charts and have them change when the Title changes automatically so it just Cycles through the whole job show the Title and job info.

Any Ideas on what I'm doing wrong?
Struggling on this, I don't know how to get each ID in the API body to be able to be used in the line chart...

**API Response Sample:**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "3": {
        "value": 177
      },
      "6": {
        "value": "2220 Three Kings "
      },
      "40": {
        "value": "In Progress"
      },
      "80": {
        "value": 41406.07
      },
      "81": {
        "value": 42076.44499999999
      },
      "82": {
        "value": 1384.888156072408
      },
```

**UPDATE**
This is what I'm trying to figure out how to do... but obviously doesn't work and can't figure out the assigning the ids to fields to actually display in the line chart.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";

const TotalLineChart = () => {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});
  // const [designHours, setdesignHours] = useState([]);
  // const [designAmount, setdesignAmount] = useState([]);
  // const [subRoughHours, setSubRoughHours] = useState([]);
  // const [subRoughAmount, setSubRoughAmount] = useState([]);
  // const [roughHours, setRoughHours] = useState([]);
  // const [roughAmount, setRoughAmount] = useState([]);
  // const [finishHours, setFinishHours] = useState([]);
  // const [finishAmount, setFinishAmount] = useState([]);
  // const [closeHours, setCloseHours] = useState([]);
  // const [closeAmount, setCloseAmount] = useState([]);
  // const [actualHours, setActualHours] = useState([]);
  // const [actualAmount, setActualAmount] = useState([]);
  
  const chart = () => {
    let designHours = [];
    let designAmount = [];
    let subRoughHours = [];
    let subRoughAmount = [];
    let roughHours = [];
    let roughAmount = [];
    let finishHours = [];
    let finishAmount = [];
    let closeHours = [];
    let closeAmount = [];
    let actualHours = [];
    let actualAmount = [];

    let headers = {
      'QB-Realm-Hostname': 'XXXXXXXXXX.quickbase.com',
      'User-Agent': 'FileService_Integration_V2.1',
      'Authorization': 'QB-USER-TOKEN XXX_XXXX_XXXXXXXXXXX',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

    let body = {"from":"bpz99ram7","select":[3,6,80,81,82,83,86,84,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,101,103,104,105,106,107,109,111,113,115,120,123,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,477,479,480,481],"where": "{40.CT. 'In Progress'}","sortBy":[{"fieldId":6,"order":"ASC"}],"groupBy":[{"fieldId":40,"grouping":"equal-values"}],"options":{"skip":0,"top":0,"compareWithAppLocalTime":false}}

   fetch('https://api.quickbase.com/v1/records/query', {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: headers,
     body: JSON.stringify(body)
   }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        for (const dataObj of res.data.data) {
          designHours.push(parseInt(dataObj.value, 88));
          designAmount.push(parseInt(dataObj.value, 91));
          subRoughHours.push(parseInt(dataObj.value, 92));
          subRoughAmount.push(parseInt(dataObj.value, 95));
          roughHours.push(parseInt(dataObj.value, 96));
          roughAmount.push(parseInt(dataObj.value, 98));
          finishHours.push(parseInt(dataObj.value, 104));
          finishAmount.push(parseInt(dataObj.value, 107));
          closeHours.push(parseInt(dataObj.value, 477));
          closeAmount.push(parseInt(dataObj.value, 480));
          actualHours.push(parseInt(dataObj.value, 479));
          actualAmount.push(parseInt(dataObj.value, 224));
        }
        setChartData({
          type: 'scatter',
          data: {
            datasets: [
              {
                data: [
                  {x: designHours, y: designAmount },
                  {x: subRoughHours, y: subRoughAmount },
                  {x: roughHours, y: roughAmount },
                  {x: finishHours, y: finishAmount },
                  {x: closeHours, y: closeAmount }
                ],
                backgroundColor: ["rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)"],
                borderWidth: 4
              }
            ]
          }
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    console.log(designHours, designAmount, subRoughHours, subRoughAmount, finishHours, finishAmount, closeHours, closeAmount, actualHours, actualAmount);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    chart();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <Line
          data={chartData}
          options={{
            responsive: true,
            title: { text: "", display: true },
            scales: {
              yAxes: [
                {
                  ticks: {
                    autoSkip: true,
                    maxTicksLimit: 10,
                    beginAtZero: true
                  },
                  gridLines: {
                    display: true
                  }
                }
              ],
              xAxes: [
                {
                  gridLines: {
                    display: true
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TotalLineChart;
```

That way I can select each field I need and display it in the line chart...

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Can you also provide sample data response you get from the post request

Comment: Updated the Question to include Sample Response.

Comment: To select that ID's value, so value of "6" for example. The bottom code example works with selecting that field ID of "6" to render. However, I can't figure out how to do that with multiple ID's and be able to assign to a line chart as shown in the top example.

Comment: In the 1st code, here `data: [{x: data[index]["6"].value, y: data[index]["6"].value }],`  it has to be `x: this.state.data[index]["6"].value` right? And also where are you getting the `index` value. Could not find any variable with index name.

Comment: Sorry that was an attempt from another component pulling an ID from another. Updated the code.

Comment: Few more clarification, when you say `have them change when the Title changes automatically `, how is the title changing automatically. What is triggering the title change? Can't you fetch new data again, on title change?

Comment: I have a Cycle component that is getting a field ID from a separate call, and cycling to show one at a time based on an inputted duration. Now I just want to input some of these numeric values based on what Job Name is displaying. When the Job Name changes, the Line Chart updates with the corresponding data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233920/discussion-between-abhishekgowda28-and-alexb801).